# Por que não posso dar getTransaction().begin() foram de um Main?

Tags: java

Estou brincando com Hibernate e me surgiu uma dúvida bem amadora.

Antes estava criando um DAO, e nele recebia um EntityManager da minha classe de teste, pelo construtor:

```
public class ExemploDao {

private EntityManager em;

public ExemploDao(EntityManager em) {
    this.em=em;
}
```

Chamado na Classe Teste:

```
EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

ExemploDao dao = new ExemploDao(em);
```

Após isso fui fazer um teste criando um `EntityManager` e chamando o `getTransaction().begin()` no meu DAO, em vez de ter que criá-lo na classe de teste:

```
    public class ExemploMovimentacaoDao {


    EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    public List<Double> getMediasPorDiaETipo(TipoMovimentacao saida, Conta conta) {

    String jpql = "select avg(m.valor) from Movimentacao m where m.conta= :pConta" 
    + " and m.tipo= :pTipo" 
    +" group by day(m.dataMovimentacao),month(m.dataMovimentacao),year(m.dataMovimentacao)";

    TypedQuery<Double> query = em.createQuery(jpql,Double.class);
    query.setParameter("pConta", conta);
    query.setParameter("pTipo", saida);


    return query.getResultList();


    em.close();
}


}
```

Ocorreu o seguinte erro na linha do `getTransaction`:

```
Syntax error on token getTransaction, identifier expected after this token.
```

Se eu colocá-lo dentro de um Main o erro desaparece. Como sou iniciante, já tive problemas parecidos, onde não consegui chamar certas coisas fora de um método main e nunca descobri ao certo o por que. Por isso peço ajuda de vocês, poderiam me explicar por que isso acontece? Se tiverem links de materiais na internet que falam sobre isso, não consegui achar nada que me tirasse essa dúvida bem básica, mas que preciso entender.

Obrigado.

Comment: por gentileza atualiza sua pergunta com a classe exemploDao completa na qual você está tentando dar gettransaction pra entendermos melhor

Comment: Pergunta atualizada com a classe, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tropeçando numa regra sintática do java, não é possível fazer esse tipo de declaração fora de um método. Uma correção simples seria:

```
public class ExemploMovimentacaoDao {


    EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();


    public List<Double> getMediasPorDiaETipo(TipoMovimentacao saida, Conta conta) {
    em.getTransaction().begin(); //estou dentro de um método agora!
    String jpql = "select avg(m.valor) from Movimentacao m where m.conta= :pConta" 
    + " and m.tipo= :pTipo" 
    +" group by day(m.dataMovimentacao),month(m.dataMovimentacao),year(m.dataMovimentacao)";

    TypedQuery<Double> query = 
    em.createQuery(jpql,Double.class);
    query.setParameter("pConta", conta);
    query.setParameter("pTipo", saida);


    return query.getResultList();


    em.close(); //ps: você nunca vai cair aqui devido ao return acima
}


}
```

Comment: Valeu, entendi. Bobeira minha, esse tipo de coisa tem que fazer dentro de um método.